# Powershell vs Cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-10

I am recently shifted from Ubuntu to Windows 10. There are two different terminals in Windows: PowerShell and Command Prompt. What is the main difference between them?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for programmers and programming questions. This question is more suitable for another site like superuser.

Comment: The following article talking about difference between PowerShell and CMD, you can have a look:http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-powershell-and-cmd/      https://www.howtogeek.com/163127/how-powershell-differs-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: Oh Thank you, Actually, I don't know about 'superuser'. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CMD originates back from the Dos days. It has a simple command structure and is a per-line instruction language.

You issue commands, get feedback and its mostly useful to start programs. In order to do more complex stuff, you usually need to use a program that performs this function specifically.

cmd does come with a lot of commands, such as copy, move, but they still are meant to perform some basic tasks.

PowerShell is more advanced language that is an extended version of the command prompt. It was created to have a windows variant of what bash is for linux, using the .net framework. All commands are native to Powershell and it can interact with the output of any program to make it do even more.

> What is the main difference between them?

cmd is a very easy language to learn, but it very limited in what it can do.

Powershell is a very complex language that is not easy to master unless you also know your way around other languages such as bash. But once you master it, it opens up a world of possibilities. Its strength is in piping commands together (redirect output from one command into the next, and redirecting that into the next etc) and being able to use the output, edit it into something more useful and then display or save that.

Comment: The "cmd is easy to learn" vs "PowerShell is hard to master" is pretty opinion based (tbh this question also attracts opinion based answers). in my opinion it's exactly the other way around.

Comment: @SimonS I suppose cmd is not easy to learn to some people, but the idea behind the statement was more to showcase the scope of what you can do in either, and how the syntax and options compare to each other. Its more a language barrier than an opinion here.

Answer (score -1):

There aren't many commons between batch and powershell.

Batch exists since 30 years and the only major extensions were made by the change from MSDOS to windows.

Batch only supports simple commands and very basic string/math operations.
It's possible to build the most necessary functionality on your own, and [that's fun for me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:463115+%5Bbatch-file%5D).
But I wouldn't use it to build productive scripts, because it's really hard to build reliable, maintainable and bullet proof scripts (And I know what I'm talking about).

Powershell has a complete own syntax style, incompatible to any other shell.
It's based on .NET objects, the commands work on objects instead of text.
It's much more powerfull than batch, but PowerShell is like all new Microsoft *future* tools, a dead horse.
It will exist for a few years until Microsoft replaces it by the next *future* tool.

IMHO, not worth to learn the syntax.

Personally, I use git-bash or cygwin for windows. But most of the time I'm working with Linux systems, to be more productive.

Comment: -1 because this answer is mostly a rant.

Comment: @gronostaj True, but it's my personal experience

Comment: So you talked to Satya Nadella and know that PowerShell will be replaced. I would also like to know him, can you introduce us somehow?

Comment: @SimonS It's not necessary to know him. But history repeats, did you know ADO, DAO, SilverLight, VisualBasic, lync, ...

Comment: @jeb PowerShell is so integrated in Windows probably more than any of the technologies you listed. Every major component HAS to be manageable with PowerShell. That is a company guideline in Microsoft. You can manage Azure, Microsoft 365, All Windows Servertools like AD, WSUS, IIS, Exchange etc. in PowerShell and they also created Core that can be used on Linux and Mac. I don't say that PowerShell won't ever be replaced, but it certainly won't happen in the near future, because right now they invest a lot into it.

Comment: @jeb Microsoft Visual Basic is still a thing in 2020. Its called Microsoft Visual Studio Basic .net or something.

Comment: @LPChip And beside the name there is nothing common to the original Visual Basic 6. Same for Windows Phone 7 vs Windows Phone 8

Comment: not true. I used to program in VB5, used VB6 a short while before going to VB.net 2008 and now use Visual Studio Code. The language is very much the same, its just using .net framework and is OOP. Its very similar how PhotoShop CS5 is nothing like PhotoShop CC 2020. Very much the same program with the same options, one is just the evolution of the other.